# How to compute of each player winning this sequence of games?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, dice

Players A and B play a sequence of independent games. Player A throws a die first and wins on a "six." If A fails, then player B throws and wins on a "five" or "six." If B fails, then A throws and wins on a "four," "five," or "six." And so on. How to find the probability of each player winning the sequence?

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** There are exactly $3$ ways that $A$ can win. Compute each case's probability separately, then add them all together to get your answer. (NOTE: Each time someone rolls the die, I call that a "Turn", for a maximum of $6$ possible Turns).

**Case 1:** $A$ wins on Turn $1$.

**Case 2:** $A$ fails on Turn $1$, $B$ fails on Turn $2$, and $A$ wins on Turn $3$.

**Case 3:** $A$ fails on Turn $1$, $B$ fails on Turn $2$, $A$ fails on Turn $3$, $B$ fails on Turn $4$, and $A$ wins on Turn $5$.

Comment: So the answer for A winning should be $$\frac{1}{6} + \frac{5}{6} \frac{4}{6} \frac{3}{6} + \frac{5}{6} \frac{4}{6} \frac{3}{6} \frac{2}{6}\frac{5}{6} = \frac{169}{324}.$$ Am I right?

Comment: That's correct! Notice that player $A$ has a very slight edge over player $B$ ($\approx 52.16\%$ chance of winning).